# Unable to install psycopg2 on Windows

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I work in a office where the PostgreSQL has been installed on server.
On my windows machine, I have pgAdmin III 1.20 installed to access the database.
I am trying to install psycopg2 in my windows system. I get this error:

```
C:\users\Tony> pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\Tony\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dobxew\psycopg2
```

I know that pg_config is available in the bin folder of the PostgreSQL. But I cannot access that location in server. Without pg_config file, I am unable to install psycopg2 in my local windows machine. I read somewhere that libpq.dll is required while building psycopg2.So I have added path of libpq.dll present in pgAdmin III 1.20 into my system path.(C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin III\1.20)
How to access the PostgreSQL database using Python then?

Comment: Is postgres installed?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Yes postgres is installed in a server which I am accessing using pgAdmin client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all those that got the same problem in 2019, the correct way to install it via pip is now :

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 4):

run this command:

```
python -m pip install Psycopg2
```

**Note:**

Open the commandprompt in the same folder as project

Answer (score 4):

The following will install prebuilt binaries for windows from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg).

```
pip install pipwin 
pipwin install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Download `psycopg2` version for your python and windows from here [win-psycopg](http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/)

Do NOT double-click the package to run. Instead, use easy_install from either [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installing-and-using-setuptools) or [distribute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.7.3).

```
C:\> easy_install psycopg2-2.6.1.win32-py2.7-pg9.4.4-release.exe
```